# Help with composition of piecewise functions

Tags: analysis, functions

Given $ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & where & x < 0 \\ 0 & where &x \geq 0 \end{cases}$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & where &|x| \geq \pi/2 \\ |sin(x)| & where & |x| < \pi/2\end{cases}$   , find $f \circ g$?

Here is my attempt. Clearly $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (-\infty, 0]$ and $g:(-\infty,+\infty) \rightarrow [0, 1]$ and $g \circ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, 1]$

Then I find it by considering it test case by test case:

$g \circ f  = \begin{cases} |sinx| & where & x \geq 0 & or & |x| < \pi/2 \\ 1 & where & |x| \geq \pi/2\end{cases}$

Where am I wrong, because there can be $x$ which satisfies both conditions so does the first get evaluated first? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**hint for $g\circ f$**

> $$x\ge 0 \implies f (x)=0 \implies $$

$$|f (x)|<\frac {\pi}{2} \implies $$
$$g (f (x))=|\sin (f (x))|=|\sin (0)|=0$$

> $$x <0\implies f (x)=x \implies $$

$$g (f (x))=g (x) $$
thus
$$|x|=-x <\frac {\pi}{2} \iff -\frac {\pi}{2}<x <0 $$
$$\implies g (f (x))=g (x)=|\sin (x)|$$
and
$$|x|=-x\ge \frac {\pi}{2}\iff x\le -\frac {\pi}{2} $$
$$\implies g (f (x))=g (x)=1$$